# what's the exactly noun form of "academic" which has the meanings like academic thesis or learning or research?

Tags: meaning, word-request

What's the exactly noun form of "academic" which has the meanings like academic thesis or learning or research ?

we know the academy means a college-like noun (`organization`), but can not for `academic thesis`.

---

such as,

```
beautiful(.adj) --- beauty(.n)
```

we can say a woman is `beautiful`, and she is a `beauty`.
when we say a research is `academic`(something with high value, high level useful), but we can not say the research is `academy`(there the mean prefers to an organization).

the `academic(.adj)`'s meaning, should corresponding to `academy(.n)`, but the `academy` is mean organization related, is not the mean of `learning` or `research` related.

Comment: While you can talk about the comparative form of an adjective, because there is a grammar rule that changes an adjective into a comparative.  There is no grammar rule that changes an adjective into a noun. Adjectives don't have noun forms.

Comment: I have edited my post, could you please check it?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still not clear.  Do you want to say something like "<academic-noun-form> is something that your writing should have". Do you have a practical example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an "XY" question here.  You think you can solve your problem by finding the noun.  But actually your problem is that you need to rephrase to avoid the noun.

However, the word that means "the nature of an academic resource" is "*academicness*"

It is unusual enough for my spell checker to think it is "not a word", but it is occasionally [used](https://prezi.com/rx72wakhiqrw/the-fishscale-of-academicness-stand-alone-resource/?token=0a0329d497e04aba4eed48a955b85081042d37c04ee7cba583caf4da7155b957&utm_campaign=share&utm_medium=copy).  (But note that this author is playing with language, she is punning on the word "scale", she is introducing a complex analogy between sealife and resources. There is a lightness in her writing that let's her get away with forming words like "academicness".

However, don't use it.  Instead, rephrase.  Don't say "Academicness is important when you write", but say "Your writing should conform to academic standards" (for example). In other words, use the adjective not the noun.

Answer (score 0):

"Beautiful" is an adjective that derives from the root word "beauty" but still "beautiful" is not an adjective form of the noun beauty. "Beautiful" and "beauty" are two seperate words in their own right.

Collegially all adjectives can be used as nouns without any modification.

If you are categorising men based on their beauty, you can say: This is the list of all the beautifuls, and that is the list of the rest.

If you are categorising researches based on their origin, you can say: This is the list of all the academics, and that is the list of all the nonacademics.

In the first sentence the word "beautifuls" stands for "beautiful ones" and likewise in the second sentence the word "academics" stands for "academic ones".

Comment: It is common usage to say "the academics" without any cast on its meaning, but not so for "the beautifuls" which does not have the same meaning as "the beauties". The first in uncomplimentary, the second not so. A beautiful is someone who tries to project the appearance of being a wonderful person, whereas a beauty is someone who looks very good.